# MVC alternative for Zend

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, containers, zend-framework-mvc

I'm trying to create my first project with Zend but it's really confusing me. IMO the configuration/bootstrapping is way too complicated.

So I was thinking about not using everything from Zend, but only the classes that seem useful to me. For the template system I could use [Savant 3.](http://phpsavant.com/)

My question is what could I use for the MVC aspect? Are there any php projects out there for this? I'm not looking for a framework, just something that handles all the requests and sends them to  my own made controllers. And then I'll send them through to Savant.

(I actually like codeigniters way of doing these things, but this is for a school project, and I need to work with Zend)

I know most of you will probably recommend just sticking with Zend's MVC, or try another framework, but that's not what I'm asking :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try pimcore ( http://www.pimcore.org/ ). It's a free CMF, built on top of the Zend Framework. You can easily click together your classes and it generates a backend for you. Also, it has strong CMS Features built in.


It provides a good way for developers to create Websites and -applications, without letting you care too much about bootstrapping and the "core" stuff. You just code your actions and views, pimcore does the rest.


Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

the whole point of zend really is for creating mvc applications if you are struggling with setting up your application there a few resources you can use   such as [ZendCasts](http://www.zendcasts.com) which will walk you through bootstrapping and setting up your error controllers etc

there is also a  project available on [github](https://github.com/epixa/Epixa/tree/master/nbproject) to give you your initial project layout so you can get straight to coding  i know you posted this some time ago  but i hope this helps if not maybe it will help someone else searching through here  :)